# Programmatically draw vector drawable / SVG on to screen

Tags: java, android, svg

I'm trying to programmatically draw an SVG on to the screen. The code below is what I've tried, when I run the program nothing shows up.

```
    public MainView(Context context) {
        hexagon = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.hex_svg);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        hexagon.setBounds(30,30,30,30);
        hexagon.draw(canvas);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` method takes the positions of the bounding box of the drawable - you've set them all to 30 so you're setting the drawable's width and height to zero.

If you want the image to be at 30x,30y with a width and height of 30 then call `setBounds(30, 30, 60, 60)`.

Also I'd call this in the `onLayout` method rather than in `onDraw`.